# How to edit(add) something already saved in a database table column?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm using java and I have a software that registers a patient and save it in a database, but there are some attributes that must be changed every time and I dont know how to do it:

My table(patients):

1.Name: (patient's name) [varchar].

2.CPF:(is a personal number that Brazilians uses to identify yourself, everybody has one), [varchar].

> 3.Notes:(patient's progress after the scessions) the patient will receive a bunch of notes, so it should be an array.

After one note saved, I would like to save more after...

Comment: Can you please be more specific, like what problem are you facing and what are things that you have tried so far. Also, please specify what are attributes that you are trying to update?

Comment: by using an sql update statement

Comment: as I guessed a question you want to update patient's age?

Comment: You can check the patient age at the time of login from date of birth and the current date and update the same.

Comment: I'll edit the post, wait please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As after the update, you Need to update the notes for the patient. So what you can do is **create a table called Patient_Notes** where **it will have the reference from the patient table (patient_id)**. By this, you can store all the notes for the patient. And also you won't need to update the same. You can just fetch the last one and also you will the have the records for all the notes that have been made.

Comment: Thank you! I would not notice it.

Comment: @PedroMartinsMelo Happy to Help! :-)